# calculate form values from radio group

Tags: javascript, forms

Trying to calculate a selection value from a radio group and values from other fields. Any 'Name' input adds a value to the Total. I need the value from the radio group to be added to that total.
Here is the HTML:

```
<FORM NAME="testauthorization" ACTION="" METHOD=POST id="exhibitreg">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><label>
          <input type="radio" name="sponsorship" value="3000" id="sponsor1" />
          $3,000</label>
        <br />
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="sponsorship" value="1500" id="sponsor2" />
          $1,500</label>
        <br />
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="sponsorship" value="1000" id="sponsor3" />
          $1,000</label>
        <br /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name 1 <INPUT NAME="Name_1" TYPE="TEXT" id="name1" onchange="updatecost(1, 50)" onkeyup="updatecost(1, 50)" VALUE="" size="30"></td>
      <td><INPUT NAME="cost_1" TYPE="TEXT" VALUE="" size="4" id="cost1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name 2<INPUT NAME="Name_2" TYPE="TEXT" id="name2" onchange="updatecost(2, 50)" onkeyup="updatecost(2, 50)" VALUE="" size="30"></td>
      <td><INPUT NAME="cost_2" TYPE="TEXT" VALUE="" size="4" id="cost2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name 3<INPUT NAME="Name_3" TYPE="TEXT" id="name3" onchange="updatecost(3, 50)" onkeyup="updatecost(3, 50)" VALUE="" size="30"></td>
      <td><INPUT NAME="cost_3" TYPE="TEXT" VALUE="" size="4" id="cost3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">Total:
        <INPUT NAME="Total" id="Total" TYPE="TEXT" VALUE="" size="8" onFocus="this.form.elements[0].focus()" >
        <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" onchange="totalcost()" onkeyup="totalcost()"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Submit">
  <input type="RESET" name="Reset" value="Reset" />
</FORM>
```

And here is the JS:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function getRadioValue(name) {
    var group = document.getElementsByName('sponsorship');
    for (var i=0;i<group.length;i++) {
        if (group[i].checked) {
            return group[i].value;
        }
    }
    return '';
}


function updatecost(num, dollars) {
    var text = document.getElementById("name" + num);
    var cost = document.getElementById("cost" + num);
    if (!text) return;
    if (!cost) return;
    if (text.value == "") {
        cost.value = "";
    }
    else {
        cost.value = dollars;
    }
    totalcost();
}
function totalcost() {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        var cost = document.getElementById("cost" + i);
        if (cost.value) total += Number(cost.value);
    }


    document.getElementById("Total").value = total;
}


//-->
</script>
```

What am I missing? By the way, in case it is not clear, I am a JS novice, so I fully accept criticism that helps me understand a more fundamental error in my approach. Simple is best for me: ;-) Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Change below function in place of existing

```
    function updatecost(num, dollars) {
        var text = document.getElementById("name" + num);
        var cost = document.querySelector('input[name="sponsorship"]:checked');
        if (!text) return;
        if (!cost) return;
        totalcost(cost);
    }
    function totalcost(cost) {
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            var text1 = document.getElementById("name" + i);
            if (text1.value != "") total += Number(cost.value);
        }
        document.getElementById("Total").value = total;
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but that is not what I am in need of. Your change merely causes the 'Name' inputs to reflect the radio button values. They need to be separate. The 'Name' values already work and need to be left the way they are. Any entry adds the value to the corresponding cost and totals at the end. What I need is for the value of the radio group to add to that total.